# design getting distorted in 3 columns CSS

Tags: css, html

Am working on a CSS for 3 columns layout and following is my css code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#header {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
#content {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#middle {
    width: 50%; /* Account for margins + border values */
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Now, here is the page where I have used this css...http://www.megahunt.in/abhijit/test/innerindex.php

The problem is when loading the #sidebar column is getting misplaced although I have defined the whole pagewrap as 100% and the #content, #middle and #sidebar both are well defined with 20%, 50% and 30% width still the whole design is getting distorted.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to your css sheet

you can geat more info **[here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

Edited: when you use `*`in your css it means it will target all html tags. basically your borders and padding when NOT using border-box takes size OUTSIDE the set width. It means that a container with 50% width and 20px padding, the real width will always be `50% + 20px padding-left + 20 px padding-right` Border box will make your borders or element padding be set INSIDE your desired width

Edited-again: Even more. when you use percent based widths, you have to take into account your margins... in your web you have set `margin:0px 5px 5px 5px;` to your `#middle`container. that means that `20% + 50% + 30% + margin` it's more than 100% so your floating elements won't be side-by-side. If you want to use margins try to use percent measures as:

```
#content {width:20%}
#middle {width:48%; margin:0 1%;}
#sidebar {width:30%}
```

that means `20+48+1+1+30= 100` that will work

Comment: @Alvaro...add it where?

Comment: well, in your css styles.. where you have the rest of css. Anyway I made a few "edits" with much better explanation. read it again if you want

Comment: @alavaro...while doing the above changes i found the #sidebar is not touching the full width..you can check it here..http://www.megahunt.in/abhijit/test/innerindex.php  the User Panel section is not taking the full space

Comment: your margin : `margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;` it's still there and after the 0 1% new one so it's overwritting the new one. You need to remove it.. and keep the width at 48% it was right

Comment: and my last comment for today (bed time), I did tell you to use `margin:0 1%` but if you want to use px based for your margin heights it won't mess up your layout so `#middle: 0px 1% 5px 1%`may work perfectly fine (as long as you remove your old one from the css)